# LINQ to SQL: "String or Binary Data Would Be Truncated" error

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I know there are several questions like this on here already, but I can't find one that relates to my problem.

I've got an SP declared like this:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SomeProc]
(
  @param1 VARCHAR(255)
  , @param2 INT
  , @param3 VARCHAR(8)
)
```

When I add the Stored Procedure to the Data Model it generates the following signature:

```
int SomeProc(string param1, int? param2, string param3)
```

The problem I have is that if I use a parameter longer than 6 characters for param3 I always get the "String  or Binary Data Would Be Truncated" error.  To me it seems like it have something to do with double-byte vs single-byte strings, but I'm not really sure.  It doesn't seem to work with other data types (NVarChar, Char, etc.) either though...

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the attributes on the generated method.

What else are you doing in the SP? It could be that you are getting that error further down.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.  Somewhere deep inside the proc there was an insert being done into a table that had the column for that parameter declared with length=6.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field length for those tables being updated